# React Native always read UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey with null

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, segment

in `react-native` `0.68.3`
using universal link iOS -> can't read `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey` always `null`

in `iOS`, `iPhone 13`, `17.1.2`

i'm using real device when debugging.

- open notes app.
- add `url` to `notes` as deeplink like `www.myapp.com/profile`
- app is opened & navigated to profile screen successfully.

but in iOS code inside `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

i can't read `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey` or `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsSourceApplicationKey`
values always `null`

this is my `AppDelegate.mm` related block

```
@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    NSString *sourceApplication = launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsSourceApplicationKey];
    NSString *sourceURL = launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey];
     if (sourceApplication) {
         NSLog(@"SHERIF_TEST UIApplicationLaunchOptionsSourceApplicationKey: %@", sourceApplication);
     } else {
         NSLog(@"SHERIF_TEST No UIApplicationLaunchOptionsSourceApplicationKey found in launchOptions");
     }
  
    if (sourceURL) {
        NSLog(@"SHERIF_TEST UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey: %@", sourceURL);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"SHERIF_TEST No UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey found in launchOptions");
    }
```

and this is `AppDelegate.h`

```
#import <React/RCTBridgeDelegate.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, RCTBridgeDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIWindow *window;

@end
```

i'm expecting for this data to be parsed successfully, because we are using SDK depend to read this data in background for tracking events `Segment` https://segment.com/

Comment: Is the application in the background or killed? Or doesn't it matter (fails in both cases)?

Comment: @user18309290 it fails for both
no `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey`